# Why do variable in an inner function return nan when there is the same variable name at the inner function declared after log

Tags: javascript, function

What's happening here? I get a different result if I declare a variable after `console.log` in the inner function

I understand that var has a functional scope and inner function can access the variable from their parent

```js
function outer() {
  var a = 2;

  function inner() {
    a++;
    console.log(a) //log NaN
    var a = 8
  }
  inner()
}
outer()
```

```js
function outer() {
  var a = 2;

  function inner() {
    a++;
    console.log(a) //log 3
    var b = 8
  }
  inner()
}
outer()
```

The log returns `NaN` in the first example and log `3` in the second example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is due to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)

The declaration of `a` in the inner function is hoisted to the top of the function, overriding the outer function's `a`, so `a` is `undefined`

`undefined++` returns `NaN`, hence your result.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
function outer() {
    var a=2;

    function inner() {
        var a;
        a++;
        console.log(a); //log NaN
        a = 8;
    }

    inner();
}

outer();
```

Rewriting your code in this way makes it easy to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Because `var` is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) through the function, you're essentially running `undefined++` which is `NaN`. If you remove `var a = 8` in `inner`, the code works as expected:

```js
function outer() {
  var a = 2;

  function inner() {
    a++;
    console.log(a);
  }
  inner();
}
outer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has the mechanism called hoisting .With the help of this mechanism javascript will automatically take all the **variable definitions** and kept it in the top of the function (*whether it may be outer function or inner function*). So in your case it will take only the variable definition and hoist it in the top . After hoisting you code will be like this

```js
function outer() {
  var a = 2;

  function inner() {
  var a;
    a++;
    console.log(a) //log NaN
    a = 8
  }
  inner()
}
outer()
```

you are trying to increment a undefined variable . This is the reason you are getting NaN error. 
So if you initialize the variable after declaration(hoisting) then you will get the result.

Answer (score -2):

They can’t access the inner function value so we have to defined globally. After globally you can use A value anywhere in the code

```
var a=0;
function outer(){
a=2;
function inner(){
a=a+1;
console.log(a)
 a = 8
}
inner()
}
outer()
```

Comment: How does this piece of code explains the issue? Can you provide an explanation of the code you have posted?

Comment: They can’t access the inner function value so we have to defined globally. After globally you can use   A value anywhere in the code

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From  Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22611869)